# G/Setting JavaScript handler defined in FXML

Tags: javascript, javafx, fxml

How can I programatically get and set the JavaScript onAction handler for a Button that is defined in FXML?

I have FXML defining a couple of Buttons and a Label

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?language javascript?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javascriptfxmlapplication.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="javaButton" layoutX="116.0" layoutY="50.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Java Button" />
        <Button fx:id="javaScriptButton" layoutX="97.0" layoutY="90.0" onAction="label.setText('hi');" text="JavaScript Button" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="100" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

One of the buttons has a Java handler defined in the Java controller for this FXML document, the other button has an inline handler defined as a JavaScript snippet.

The Java document handler is as follows:

```
package javascriptfxmlapplication;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Button javaScriptButton, javaButton;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    }

}
```

All works well. But is it possible to dynamically get/set the JavaScript to be executed by the button?

As far as i can see the FXML loader creates a javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ScriptEventHandler for buttons defined in the FXML to have JavaScript handlers, but ScriptEventHandler is private and there is no obvious way to programatically get or set the JavaScript text.

My aim is to create a JavaScriptButton that extends Button. It has drag and drop event handlers such that you can drop some text (JavaScript) on the button and that JavaScript gets executed when the button is pressed. This I have implemented by explicitly creating a JavaScriptEngine and adding a Script property to my JavaScriptButton. It just seems a shame since much of this work must have already been done in core JavaFX.